# Start git bash in current working directory with shortcut key

Tags: terminal, git-bash

I Want to start Git bash in (current) directory I'm standing in

I created shortcut key for my git bash but I don't know universal flag or path to open it in the folder I'm currently standing in, it opens in home path as default

[image]

any workarounds kind people?

Comment: Don't you already have a right click > open git bash from here?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Yes but it's kinda annoying